# Plot points over choropleth map made in R with geom_sf

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a map that plots schools in New Orleans and shows the median income of the neighborhood around those schools. I can successfully make a map that shows the location of schools, and a choropleth map of median income, but I am having difficulty making a map that shows both.

This is my data, which is saved as a dataframe called "schools":

```
school latitude longitude
a 29.97240 -90.11388
b 29.95081 -90.04993
c 29.92019 -90.12129
d 29.93410 -90.12936
e 29.99227 -90.05228
f 30.00404 -90.10053
g 29.92318 -90.11448
h 30.02866 -89.94944
i 30.00715 -90.05250
j 29.91816 -89.99931
k 29.97450 -90.07600
```

This is how I make a map with schools plotted:

```
census_api_key("insert key here")
options(tigris_class = "sf")
orleans <- tracts(state="LA", county="Orleans", cb=T) #divided by Census tracts...separate question, but I'd also like to know how to divide this by zip code

ggplot(orleans) + 
  geom_sf(color="#0d394e", size = 0.5) +
  geom_point(data=schools, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude), color="red", size=3) +
  theme_void()
```

And a choropleth map:

```
orleans_income = get_acs(geography="tract", year=2016, variables = "B19013_001E", county="Orleans", state="LA", geometry=T)

g = ggplot(orleans_income, aes(fill=estimate)) +
  geom_sf(color="#0d394e", size = 0.5) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="Reds", direction=1, name="Median Income")
```

However, when I try to add this code to lay points over the choropleth map, I get an error: **"Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'estimate' not found"**

```
g + geom_point(data=schools, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude), color="red", size=3)
```

Comment: You'ver not given us a MWe, so it's difficult to test ourt ideas, but I suspect you're getting the error because you have`aes(fill=estimate)` in the `ggplot()` call rather than in the `geom_sf()` call.  By default, `geom`s have `inherit.aes=TRUE`.  So move your `fill=estimate` into the `geom_sf()` call.  or set `inherit.aes=FALSE` in your `geom_point()`.  If neither work, post a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you more effectively.

Comment: Thank you, that works. I don't understand what I need to add to make my question reproducible. I provided the data and I cannot provide the census key as that is private.

Comment: Happy to have helped!  In this case, we need data.  You've given us your `schools` data (Though not in a very useful format: the output from `dput(schools)` would have been better.  Then we can just cut and paste it) but not `orleans` or `orleans_income`.  So there's no way we can test OUR code on YOUR data to see if it give the answer YOU want.